# Find a property in an array and get the index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update a boolean property of all objects in an array with the same user_id. Below i organzied my MVC framework and tried to present the code as brief as possible.

Model:

```
 var posts = [{id:1, user_id:1, is_following:true},
    {id:2, user_id:1, is_cool:true},
    {id:2, user_id:2, is_cool:false}];
```

View:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="post in posts">
 <button ng-click="unCool(post.user_id,$index)"  ng-if="post.is_cool === true">
 Cool
 </button>
 <button ng-click="makeCool(post.user_id,$index)" ng-if="post.is_cool === false" >
 not Cool
 </button>
 <p>{{post.id}}</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.makeCool =function(userid, index){
  //this is an ajax request for brevity i excluded the service 
  coolService.makeCool(user_id)
        .success(function (data) {
             $scope.posts[index].is_following = true;
   //How to find other indexes with same user id and make them true too
          }).
        error(function(error, status) {         
          //do something        
      });
}

$scope.unCool =function(userid, index){
  //this is an ajax request for brevity i excluded the service 
  coolService.unCool(user_id)
        .success(function (data) {
             $scope.posts[index].is_following = false;
   //How to find other indexes with same user id and make them false too
          }).
        error(function(error, status) {         
          //do something        
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Angular, jQuery or lo-dash functions here... You can use the native `Array.prototype.filter` method to slim the array down to only the matching elements and the native `Array.prototype.forEach` method to update each matching element.

```
$scope.posts
  .filter(function(post) {
    return post.user_id === userid;
  }).forEach(function(post) {
    post.is_following = true;
  });
```

Comment: this one creates a redundant intermediate array. Everything can be handled with one `map` and `if` inside

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). You don't need the `$index` (and probably not a good idea incase you decide to filter your `ng-repeat).

```
$scope.makeCool =function(userid){
  coolService.makeCool(userid)
        .success(function (data) {
             var posts_to_update = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, function(post) {
               return post.user_id == user_id;
             });
             // Now iterate through and update the boolean property
             angular.forEach(posts_to_update, function(post) {
               post.is_following = true;
             })
          }).
        error(function(error, status) {         
          //do something        
      });
}
```

You can do something similar for `unCool`

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash library you can easily do this operation.
first group your data by "user_id" property.then using loop set true/false in boolean property.so your boolean property will set for "user_id'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object structure in `posts` is not consistent. I guess the object with property `is_following` shouldn't be updated and get a property `is_cool` assigned.

In case whatever logic is there it is pure JavaScript question. I'll provide code on example of `makeCool` function.

```
 coolService.makeCool(user_id)
    .success(function (data) {
         $scope.posts[index].is_following = true;
         $scope.posts.map(function(post){//iterate all posts
                if(post.user_id === user_id && post.hasOwnProperty('is_cool')){//and for those that belong to same user and already have property is_cool
                        post.is_cool = true;//set coolness
                }
          });
      }).
```

Comment: Map is creating an unnecessary intermediate array here. Foreach is the functionality you're looking for. ;)